# Clone an object with closure

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to clone an object with closures. Tried `angular.copy()`

```js
function Foo() {
  var data;

  this.x = function(val) {
    if (val) {
      data = val;
    }
    return data;
  }
}

var a = new Foo();
var b = angular.copy(a);

b.x(); // undefined
a.x(5); // set x
b.x(); // 5. expected undefined
```

Comment: what is your problem? a.x() is undefined so b.x() is also. Then you define a.x() and since b is a dynamic copy it is also set to 5

Comment: All that `angular.copy()` will do is copy the references. It cannot create a whole new closure for the "b" version of that function to exist in.

Comment: You're copying the function in `a` into `b`. It's the same function so references the same data. What's wrong with `var a = new Foo(), b = new Foo()`? I'm not sure what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own `clone` method on your `Foo` object if you'd like. You'd just have to make sure to clone any relevant data too (if `data` f.e. is an object the method below would just store a reference to the same object).

```js
function Foo() {
  var data;

  this.x = function(val) {
    if (val) {
      data = val;
    }
    return data;
  }
  this.clone = function() {
    var n = new Foo();
    n.x(data);
    return n;
  }
}

var a = new Foo();
var b = a.clone();

a.x(5); // set x
console.log("a.x: " + a.x()); // 5
console.log("b.x: " + b.x()); // undefined
```

Comment: The `n.data = this.data;` line will be confusing given that within the Object, `data` is used to refer to a closed variable, not a property to the Object. Basically, using the API provided (setting data with function `x`), the line will tend to be essentially the same as `n.data = undefined;`. I don't think that this is the question's requested / intended behaviour.

Comment: More simply, I think OP is hoping to copy the closed values, not just the exposed values.

Comment: In `this.clone`: `n.x(data);`